# Android Studio Keymap

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I use Android Studio Version 0.3.2 and the 0.3.7 on a Windows 7 Pro computer

I have for the keymap something like "Meta+N" for New. What is Meta?
Normally I think that I need something like Ctrl+N . Is there a setting that I have to change ?
Also for copy, paste ... I have Meta instead of Ctrl.

Comment: Just guessing, but, could it be the windows key? It's probably called meta because it has a different name on different OSs. "Command" on Mac, "Windows" on Windows and "Super" on Ubuntu.

Comment: For copy you need normally "Windows"+"c". At my Android Studio "Meta"+"c". It don't work with "Windows"+"c" so it have to be something else . Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Zoltan is right. It's Command/Windows key. You can add new keystroke, or remove previous. It's look like you imported someone's settings, or Idea works with invalid keybord layout. As far as I remember, there was an combobox to select one of predefined keymaps, like Windows/macos/eclipse-like/etc.

Comment: Thx. I found the combobox under File > Settings > IDE Settings > Keymap, and set it to 'Eclipse' instead of 'Eclipse (MAC OS X)'. The Windows key did not work as the meta key in my case, however.